# How can the jQuery code for initialization be simplified?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At first, while page loading, I am suppressing some of the elements visibility. Based on the function clicked, then, each of the element will displayed. My aim is to simplify the below code while page load. Any idea?

```
$("span[class='user-name']").css("display", "none");
$("span[class='password']").css("display", "none");
$("span[class='urlcontent']").css("display", "none");
$("span[class='email']").css("display", "none");
$("#About").css("display", "none");
$("#Careers").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: The answer marked as correct is seems to be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery**

Note that you can have multiple selectors separated by commas in a query.

```
$(".user-name,.password,.urlcontent,.email,#About,#Careers").hide();
```

**CSS**

You can also hide the elements by simply using CSS.

```css
.user-name, .password, .urlcontent, .email, #About, #Careers {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You should always explain your answers with at least one or two sentences, so people can understand the reason behind it.

Answer (score 2):

add a class to the elements you need to hide

```
<span class="user-name hide"></span>
```

and hide them on dom ready

```
$('.hide').hide();
```

or just use css

```
.hide{display:none;}
```

I think this method is more cleaner because changing class names or adding replacing them later on will not mess up your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class "hidden", which has `display: none;` in CSS, which I apply to everything that should be hidden and only dynamically be shown:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And then in my HTML I add that class:

```
<span class="password hidden">...</span>
```

So I only need to do something when I want to **show** it:

```
$("span.password").show();
```

or

```
$("span.password").removeClass("hidden");
```

Also, you do not need to do `[class=password]`. Just use the proper jQuery/Sizzle selector for class:

```
$("span.password")
$("span.email")
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can merge your Ids and classes in just one line and display them to none
the next code will apply for all your span elements So if you want to specify spans use span[[class='user-name']]

```
 $('span,#About,#Careers').css("display", "none");
```

or you can hide all of them by using .hide()

```
$('span,#About,#Careers').hide();
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete, it looks like OP wants to only hide a subset of span elements, not all of them.

Comment: A little more text to describe your code would make this a valid answer